# Move the axis ticks, but not the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Is there an easy way to move the ticks of an axis with discrete values so that they are on the plot limits and midway between two labels?

My code:

```
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

p2 +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5),
             colour = "gray92") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0.5))
```

[image]

What I would like (notice ticks on x axis):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option or hack would be to use a continuous x scale which allows to set the breaks and ticks midway between two labels and add the "axis labels" via a `geom_text` or a `geom_label` as I do in my code below. To this end convert variable to be mapped on x to a numeric.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(as.numeric(factor(cut)), price, group = cut)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5),
             colour = "gray92") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:5 + .5, labels = ~ rep("", length(.x)), expand = c(0, .125)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = cut, y = -Inf), data = ~ dplyr::distinct(.x, cut), 
             fill = NA, vjust = 1, 
             label.size = 0, 
             label.padding = unit(5, "pt")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]